# linking files in c( multiple definition of...)

Tags: c, linker, cfile, hfile

Im trying to link a few files in c and im getting this erorr: 
"multiple definition of createStudentList"

my main.c:

```
#include "students.h" 

int main(void) 
{  

  return 0;
}
```

students.h:

```
#ifndef _students_h_
#define _students_h_
#include "students.c" 

bool createStudentList();
#endif
```

students.c:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct Students
{
  int id;
  double average;
} Student;

bool createStudentList()
{
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you including `students.c` in `students.h`? It should be the other way around.

Comment: Your file are all wrong. The `students.h` file should create the function declaration (like it does now) and maybe also the structure definition. It should *not* include the source file `student.c`. Instead the `student.c` source file should include `student.h`.

Comment: You also need to understand how `#include` works: It basically copy-pastes the included file into the file being parsed. That means the *definition* (implementation) of `createStudentList` will be inside the header file. So if you then build both `main.c` *and* `student.c` then you will have two implementations of `createStudentList`: Once in the `main.c` function, because of its inclusion in the `student.h` header file; And once in the `student.c` source file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the includes, you have the function `createStudentList()` defined in both *main.o* and *student.o*, which leads to the linker error you observe.

I would suggest to do the following. The structure (type) definition and function prototype should go into the header file:

```
#ifndef _students_h_
#define _students_h_

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Students
{
  int id;
  double average;
} Student;


bool createStudentList(void);
#endif
```

and the actual code in the sourcefile, which includes the headerfile

```
#include "students.h"

bool createStudentList(void)
{
  return true; 
}
```

Now you can use both the type and the function `createStudentList` in other source files by including `students.h`.

Comment: oh i see and if i have defines  they go into the h file as well?

Comment: @zoids3 There is no general rule for that. Thumbrule is: if the defines are also needed/used in other sourcefiles, then put it into a header file. Otherwise, it depends on the coding style and the nature of those defines

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#include "students.c"` from students.h. Because of this the definition is occuring twice - one from students.h and another from students.c - hence the clash.

Just remove the above mentioned line and also add `#include <stdbool.h>` in your students.h. Do these modifications and your code will compile and link fine.